# Second notification cancels out first one - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarm

I am trying to manage two separate notifications in my project. I have a notification that send to the user when a bill is due, and a notification that is sent when a payment is successful.

When I call the notification from my AlarmReceiver class, the payment notification is called, even for the bill is due notification. I think this is because it is called last in the OnReceive, and so this cancels out the bill is due notification.

Is there a type of if or switch statement that I can put in my OnReceive, to see check which request code has been called (101 or 102) and then call that notification?

Here is my code:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "bills.channelId";


    /**
     * @param context
     * @param intent
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // run notification 1
        userHasBill(context, intent);
        // run notification 2
        userPaymentIsSuccessful(context, intent);


    }

    /**
     * Notification to call when the user sets a reminder
     * @param intent
     */
    public void userHasBill(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(EmailActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(101, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

        // Notification Builder and setting parameters?
        Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle("Bill Reminder!")
                .setContentText("Just a reminder that you have a bill due!")
                .setTicker("Just a reminder that you have a bill due!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "bills",
                    IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);


    }


    /**
     * Notification to call when bill payment is successful
     *
     * @param context current context
     * @param intent  intent to go to home activity
     */
    public void userPaymentIsSuccessful(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(EmailActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(102, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

        Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle("Payment successful!")
                .setContentText("Your payment was successful!")
                .setTicker("Your Payment was Successful!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "bills",
                    IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);


    }


}
```

I already tried to make two channel IDs, but it still calls the second notification that's in the OnReceive

Answer (score 1):

You're posting two notifications with the same id (equals 1). These ids should be unique for different notifications.

[NotificationManager.notify()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification))

> public void notify (int id, 
>                   Notification notification).
>   Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. **If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.**

Comment: I changed the notification ID to 2 for the second notification, it now sends both notifications